# Store result from a promise in a variable

Tags: node.js

Hey there so I'm trying to store the result of a promise in a variable because I have some code that doesn't work inside of the promise.

(I'm pretty new to node.js so a bit of explanation would be awesome!)

And how would I use a async await?

Heres my current code:

```
const rbx = require("noblox.js")

var myblurb;
rbx.getBlurb(166962499).then(function (blurb) {
  myblurb = blurb;
});

console.log(myblurb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that sets your variable will get called after your function completes, not during it. Therefore your variable is still undefined after calling `rbx.getBlurb` because it returns a promise that will complete later on.

**Using async/await:**

One way to get what you're after is to use `await`. This can only be done within a function that is declared as `async`, and that will mean the function now will also return a Promise.  If you're okay with that, then you can do it like this:

```
async function doStuff() {
  var myblurb;
  myblurb = await rbx.getBlurb(166962499);
  console.log(myblurb);
}
```

This tells your function to stop and wait until the promise from calling `getBlurb` has resolved, and assign the resolved value to your local variable.

Note that if there's an error (either a promise rejection or a thrown exception) then your function will pass that along. You could surround it all with a try/catch to handle that if you need.

**Operating Within then**

If you don't want to make your function return a promise then you could alternately do this:

```
rbx.getBlurb(166962499).then(function (blurb) {
  const myblurb = blurb;
  console.log(myblurb);
  // myblurb is only useful within this 'then' resolve function
});
```

It just means that you have to do the rest of your functionality that relies on the `myblurb` variable within that resolve function of the `then`.

Note that whoever is calling this code needs to understand that it will be asynchronous, so it should either use a callback function or `Promise` to give its results back to the caller (if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function where assignment is happening will be called after promise is called. Console.log will be executed before that. So it will always log undefined. 
You have to do console.log inside function of you can also use async await so solve this.